# Split a /path/to/file

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have an explicit path to a file:

```
/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
```

I need to `cd /aaa/bbb` and perform an operation on `ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt`.

I got the first bit figured out:

```
df_test=/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
cd $( echo ${df_test} | awk -F/ '{print "/"$2"/"$3}' )
```

How do I then chop off the first two steps in the path, and operate on the remainder? Additionally, I won't know in advance how deep these files will be. I might have

```
/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.txt
/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg/hhh/iii.txt
```

I just need to change directories to /aaa/bbb, and operate on the remaining relative path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a standard shell:

```
$ path=/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
$ tail="${path#/*/*/}"
$ head="${path%/$tail}"
$ echo "$head" "$tail"
/aaa/bbb ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
```

`"${path#/*/*/}"` is the value of `path` but with the (shortest) leading part  matching `/*/*/` removed, that is, your tail part. Then `"${path%/$tail}"` is `path` with a slash and the tail part removed.

That will produce broken results if the path doesn't have enough components, so you may want to check that first.

Alternatively, in Bash we can use a regular expression match within `[[ .. ]]` and pick up matching pieces:

```
$ if [[ $path =~ (/[^/]+/[^/]+)/(.*) ]]; then 
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi 
/aaa/bbb ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
```

`[[ ... ]]` works as a condition, so it's simple to use an `if` here to make sure the path has enough components.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I like `cut` for this instead:

```
$ echo "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt" | cut -d'/' -f4-
ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
```

You simply have to adjust the `-f` argument with however deep you'd like it to parse down in the directory tree.

This shows how to get rid of the 1st two fields using `awk`:

```
$ echo "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt" | awk -F'/' -v OFS='/' '{$1=$2=$3=""; print}' | sed 's#///##'
ccc/ddd/eee/fff.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the prefix is static, you could use parameter expansion to strip it off:

```
df_test=/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg/hhh/iii.txt
cd /aaa/bbb
operate=${df_test#/aaa/bbb}
echo Operating on "$operate"
```